# How to make widget title accept php?

Tags: php, widgets, widget-text

I am trying to make widgets accept php, but without resorting to plugins.

So far I have enabled php for the widget_text but cant make it work for widget_title.

I am using the following code in functions.php:

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

What would I have to do to enable php in the title as well?

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: i need to work around a commercial theme and plugin i dont want to edit, which handles all widgets & sidebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter `widget_title` and a "virtual" shortcode. Of course, as [One Trick Pony](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90360/how-to-make-widget-title-accept-php#comment122246_90360) points out, the "why" (and the "what") is essential to find a proper solution...

Supposing the widget title was `Title [php] More Title`:

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'pseudo_php_wpse_90360', 10, 3 );

function pseudo_php_wpse_90360( $title, $instance, $id_base )
{
    if( FALSE === strpos( $title, '[php]' ) )
        return $title;

    $break_it = explode( '[php]', $title );

    $title = $break_it[0] . 'hello world' . $break_it[1];

    return $title;
}
```

The output is `Title hello world More Title`.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('widget_title', function($title_option, $all_options, $widget_id){

  // modify $title_option as you wish

  return $title_option;

}, 10, 3);
```

Note that a lot of 3rd party plugins don't apply this filter on their widgets, so this might not always work.

Create a new plugin and put this code inside it, no need for any `eval` here.
Same for the code you have for `widget_text`.

And if you insist on allowing PHP code input from the widget settings, at least save it inside .php files, not the database (what if someone gains unauthorized access to your db?). Then you can `require` / `include` them.